# scanln() go method not waiting for out when run using docker-compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, containers

I have a main.go file having simple code to take input from user

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // take input
    var num int
    fmt.Println("Enter number between 2 and 20: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&num)
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```

I'm trying to run it in docker container.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.18-alpine

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  test:
      build: .
```

When I'm building it using `docker build -t "sample:v1"` command and running it using `docker run -it sample:v1`, it is working as expected.

But when I'm using `docker-compose up` it doesn't wait for the user to give input. Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Tell docker compose that you want it interactive, i.e. find the equivalent of `-it`

Comment: @BurakSerdar Is it a sarcasm?

Comment: No it is not. Unless you tell it to do it interactive, the job in the container will not have an attached terminal. Find the equivalent of `-it` flag.

Comment: There is a `tty` option: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#tty

Comment: `docker-compose up --tty` and `docker-compose up tty` both are not working

Comment: tty is an option for docker-compose file. Add that to the docker-compose file. It is not a flag.

Comment: Since Compose can start multiple containers, `docker-compose up` doesn't necessarily know where to send stdin.  The linked question has some alternate invocations that may work better.